# Are function definitions, function calls and declarations statements in C?

Tags: c, function, declaration, definition

When we talk about statements in C, we usually think of expression statements, looping statements, conditional branching statements, and unconditional jumping statements.

Are the following considered statements in the C programming language:

- function definitions (including the `main` function's definition, which varies from program to program. In Bash, a function definition is a command, which I think is synonym of statement.),
- function calls, (which I guess can be expression statements, but I am not sure about a call to a function which returns `void`)
- declarations (e.g. object, function, type declarations)?

If some of them are not statements, what are they respectively?

Thanks.

Comment: are you preparing for the exam?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Self learner trying to go over fundamental knowledge.

Comment: from the syntax: `stmt := expr + ';'`  (plus: compound statements, ignored here) And function calls are just expressions. Same for assignments.

Comment: You can find a syntax in the back of K&R. Or, as a yacc-specification in the source for some/most compilers. (Beware: these can be polluted by syntax-hacks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C (opposite to C++) declarations are not statements.

From the C Standard (6.8 Statements and blocks)

> Syntax

```
1 statement:
    labeled-statement
    compound-statement
    expression-statement
    selection-statement
    iteration-statement
    jump-statement
```

The C++ Standard includes also

```
declaration-statement
```

A call of a function (even if the function has return type void) can be an expression statement or a part of an expression.

From the C Standard (6.8.3 Expression and null statements)

> 2 The expression in an expression statement is evaluated as **a void
>   expression** for its side effects

and (6.3.2.2 void)

> 1 The (nonexistent) value of **a void expression (an expression that
>   has type void)** shall not be used in any way, and implicit or
>   explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an
>   expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
>   expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression
>   is evaluated for its side effects.)

A function definition is at the same time a function declaration.

From the C Standard (6.7 Declarations)

> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set
>   of identifiers. **A definition of an identifier is a declaration for
>   that identifier that**:
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;

Consider this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    goto L1;

    L1:; char *s = "Hello";

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello
```

However if to remove the semicolon after the label `L1:` (that is to remove the null statement) the compiler will issue an error because a declaration is not a statement and a label may not be used with a declaration.

Comment: Thanks. Why are declarations not statements? I thought they were. What are their fundamental differences?

Comment: @Tim It is another question.:) In C++ declarations are statements.

Comment: Do you find any authorative references that say that C doesn't treat declartions as statements, but C++ does? Aside from arbitrary designation, what is the reason between C and C++ treating declarations differently as statements or not?

Comment: Thanks. (1)  "A function definition is at the same time is a function declaration." Do you mean a function definition and a function declaration are the same concept? What do you mean instead? (2) `char *s = "Hello";` is a definition, so is a declaration?

Comment: There's no particular reason, they're just syntactic categories. The C language definition *could* have stated that a declaration is a kind of statement, it just happens that it didn't. It would make no difference to the meaning of the language (except perhaps that you could have a label on a declaration). (BTW, in C++ I believe a declaration is syntactically a statement only if it appears inside the body of a function.)

Comment: @Tim char *s = "Hello"; is a declaration of an object and at the same time a definition of the object.

Comment: @Tim In the C++ Standard opposite to the C Standard declarations are listed among kinds of statements.

Comment: @Tim: All definitions are declarations; not all declarations are definitions. Roughly, a definition causes an entity to be created, while a declaration provides a visible name for something but may or may not cause it to be created. `void func(void);` is a function declaration. `void func(void) { printf("Hello\n"); }` is a definition that also provides a declaration.

Comment: @Tim As for the question why declarations are not statements in C then historically before adopting the C99 Standard you might not mix statements and declarations. There was a clear separation between them. Declarations were placed in the beginning of a block.  Though now you may place a declaration not only in the beginning of a block declarations as usual are not statements.